# Writing a jagged array of objects(which contain an integer and string) to the console window

Tags: c#, arrays

This is my first question so I apologize if I break rules, etc.

Essentially, I have a jagged array(Apples) containing objects(Worms).  The main trouble I've come across is writing the elements of this array to the console window. I more or less don't understand how to properly index the array.

```
        object[][] Apples = new object[2][];   //This says that we will declare a jagged array of objects.  Our Apples array will contain 2 elements, each of which is a single dimensional array

        Apples[0] = new object[2]; //initializing the elements, saying element 0 of apples will be an object, in our case an array, with 2 element
        Apples[1] = new object[2]; //initializing the elements, saying element 1 of apples will be an object, in our case an array, with 2 elements

        Apples[0][0] = new Worm(22, "Matt"); //the first element in the array of worm in the first element of the array of apple
        Apples[0][1] = new Worm(23, "Marty");//the second element in the array of worm in the first element of the array of apple
        Apples[1][0] = new Worm(24, "Mike"); //the first element in the array of worm in the second element of the array of apple
        Apples[1][1] = new Worm(25, "Pete"); //the second element in the array of worm in the second element of the array of apple

        for (int i = 0; i < Apples.Length; i++)  //this is the only thing i'm having trouble with
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Apples[i].LongLength; j++)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Element[{0}][{1}]: ", i, j);
                System.Console.Write(Apples[i].ToString());
                System.Console.Write("\n\r");
            }
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine("\n\rPress any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
```

My worm class is as follows:

```
    public class Worm
{
    public Worm(int WormAge, string WormName) //constructor that accepts two arguments
    {
        int age = WormAge;
        string name = WormName;
    }
}
```

Comment: This way? `System.Console.Write(Apples[i][j].ToString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the `Worm` incorrectly, try using `Apples[i][j]` instead of `Apples[i]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Apples.Length; i++)  //this is the only thing i'm having trouble with
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Apples[i].LongLength; j++)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Element[{0}][{1}]: ", i, j);
        System.Console.Write(Apples[i][j].ToString());
        System.Console.Write("\n\r");
    }
}
```

You may also need to override `Worm.ToString()` to get a more meaningful message for each `Worm`.

```
public class Worm
{
    // ...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Worm '{0}', age {1}", name, age);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing it that way yields the following output:

    Element[0][0]:
ConsoleApplication1.Worm
Element[0][1]:
ConsoleApplication1.Worm
Element[1][0]:
ConsoleApplication1.Worm
Element[1][1]:
ConsoleApplication1.Worm

Comment: Yes that's right, I added an example of overriding the `ToString()` method, without your own implementation of `ToString()` it will just print the type (`ConsoleApplication1.Worm`).

Comment: It's taken me forever to verify this(I haven't had a lot of time), but it worked fantastically.  Thanks!